# Child pom's are not working with multi module spring boot project

Tags: maven, spring-boot

I have a parent pom.xml.

There are 2 child pom.xml

But when i do clean for all of them, they cant clean. It gives errors

I tried lots of  things. Made same answers from questions but they did not work.

The error is:

> Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory=C:\Users\caydin\Applications\evault\yyy "->Dmaven.home=C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA >2019.1\plugins\maven\lib\maven3" "-Dclassworlds.conf=C:\Program >Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2019.1\plugins\maven\lib\maven3\bin\m2.conf" "->javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA >2019.1\lib\idea_rt.jar=55677:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA >2019.1\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program >Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2019.1\plugins\maven\lib\maven3\boot\plexus->classworlds-2.5.2.jar" org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher -Didea.version2019.1 >clean
>   [INFO] Scanning for projects...
>   [ERROR] [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
>   [FATAL] Non-resolvable parent POM for com.xxx:yyy-console-backend:0.0.1->SNAPSHOT: Failure to find com.xxx:com.xxx:pom:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT in >http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/ was cached in the local repository, resolution >will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or >updates are forced and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line >5, column 13
>   [FATAL] Non-resolvable parent POM for com.xxx:com.xxx.frontend:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: >Failure to find com.xxx:com.xxx:pom:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT in >http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/ was cached in the local repository, resolution >will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or >updates are forced and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line >5, column 13
>    @

Parent pom

```
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>LATEST</version>
        <!--2.1.3.RELEASE-->
        <relativePath></relativePath>
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.xxx</groupId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <artifactId>com.xxx</artifactId>
    <name>yyyy-console</name>
    <description>xxx E-Money (Project:yyyy)</description>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>


    <modules>
        <module>src/main/java/com/xxx/yyyy/backend</module>
        <module>src/main/java/com/xxx/yyyy/web</module>
    </modules>
```

child pom for backend

```
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.xxx</groupId>
        <artifactId>com.xxx</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>yyyy-console-backend</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>yyyy-console-backend</name>
    <description>xxx E-Money (Project:yyyy)</description>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>


    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>//and dependencies for spring
```

other pom.xml is same with backend.

At first there were only main pomxml. Then i created child pom, took all spring-boot dependencies to other two child pom.

the structure

````
   xxx
   pom.xml
   backend
      pom.xml
   web
      pom.xml```
````

Comment: First remove `LATEST` from the version tag in your parent second the entries in `<module>src/main...</module>` is simply wrong cause it should be `<module>backend</module>` ...

Comment: I changed 'to ''2.1.4.RELEASE''' . i cant put '''backend''' alone. it gives error. intellij puts this in way. i dnt know why. maybe it cant recognize pomxml for child poms because java classes are red.